# Android MediaPlayer: сохранение при повороте экрана

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-sdk, android-mediaplayer, viewmodel

Моё приложение в разных ситуациях может проигрывать звуки. Звуки короткие - порядка 1 секунды. Звуки загружаются из интернета:

```
        var player = MediaPlayer()
        player.setDataSource(this, file.uri, file.headers)
        player.prepareAsync()
```

Звуков может быть много и загрузка их может занимать заметное время. Сейчас экземпляры MediaPlayer хранятся в Activity. Соответственно, при повороте экрана Activity вместе с плеерами уничтожается и создаётся заново. При повороте экрана все аудио файлы заново скачиваются и интернета. Это приводит к задержке инициализации и мне кажется для пользователя будет неожиданностью, что при поворотах экрана расходуется его интернет трафик.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно сделать более правильно?

Возможные варианты, про которые я прочитал в документации:

1. Хранить MediaPlayer во ViewModel
2. Хранить в Fragment, сделав ему setRetainInstance(true)
3. Может быть можно как-то сохранять MediaPlayer в функции onSaveInstanceState?
4. Вроде как можно сделать Service, чтобы проигрывать в фоне, но мне кажется, что для моей задачи это слишком сложно. Мне не нужно проигрывать звуки в фоне. Если проигрывание будет прерываться при повороте экрана - это допустимо.

Какой из этих вариантов лучше? Может быть есть лучшее решение?

Comment: Менее секунды, наверное лучше пользоваться SoundPool, загружать и хранить в "статике", например в Application

Comment: SoundPool не имеет функций загрузки файлов с интернета. Как в него можно загрузить файлы из сети? Насколько корректно хранить его в Application? Все примеры, которые я нашёл, хранят его в Activity.

Comment: Сохранить сначала в файл, что разумно для повторного использования

Comment: А для сохранения файлов нужно дополнительное разрешение? Если нужно, то получается нужно будет объяснять пользователю зачем приложению, которое вроде бы не работает с файлами нужно разрешение для работы с файлами.

Comment: Кроме того у меня 2 гигабайта аудио файлов. Все скачанные хранить локально не желательно, а редко используемые нужно удалять. Получается нужно городить какой-то менеджер файлов, который бы их скачивал и удалял редко используемые если объём хранилища превысил заданный.

Comment: если во внутреннюю папку приложения сохранять файлы, то можно без разрешения. Я не знаю логику и назначение вашего приложения, не хотите возиться удаляйте все